# Calling method from another php file

Tags: php

So I'm trying my hand at creating php methods from scratch. My classes aren't exactly classes yet, I'm still working on that. Anyway, my issue's I can't seem to get the values I expect from my database. Here's a snippet of my code:

file1.php

```
<?php function dbConnect() {
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "music_root", "", "music");
if($connection->connect_error) {
    return null;
}

return $connection;}

function getCategory() {
$cn = dbConnect();
if($cn == null) {
    echo "Failed to connect to database.";
} else {
    $fetchQuery = mysqli_query($cn, "SELECT * FROM tbl1 ORDER BY 'Name'") or die(mysqli_error($cn));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($fetchQuery) > 0) {
        while($item = mysqli_fetch_array($fetchQuery)) {
            return $item["Name"];
        }
    }
}} ?>
```

Here's the snippet of how I call the above method in file2.php

```
<?php ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  include_once("file1.php");
  $con = dbConnect();
  $updateStat = false;  ?>

<div>
    <label>Genre</label>
    <select id="genre" name="genre" value="Please select genre">
    <option value="<?php $con->getCategory() ?>"></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I've tried printing a message at the start of the method to see if the it's being called but the message did not print either so I was wondering, what am I possibly missing here?

Comment: You never included `file1.php` in `file2.php`?!

Comment: use require_once() when "including" fails, requiere throwns an E_ERROR, include just throws a NOTICE

Comment: You have many errors in your code! 1. Where is `dbConnect()` defined? 2. I don't think the function `dbConnect()` returns a object which has the method `getCategory()`, otherwise please show us your class definition. Also your function `getCategory()` of file1 is never used in your code right now! So you would have to tell us why it is relevant to your question

Comment: dbConnect is declared as another method in file1.php. I didn't think I needed to include the entire file1.php to solve the problem. Anyway, I've updated my post.

Comment: @user1597438 Now you said it's declared as a method, so is the entire code in file1 a class definition and if yes where do you create your instance ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have serveral mistakes in your code ... i guess, you don't use OOP (classes) so i modfiy a example which should work .. .if not, please post error messages

file1.php

```
function getCategory($cn) {
   $out = array();
   if($cn == null) {
       echo "Failed to connect to database.";
   } else {
      $fetchQuery = mysqli_query($cn, "SELECT * FROM tbl1 ORDER BY 'Name'") or die(mysqli_error($cn));
      if(mysqli_num_rows($fetchQuery) > 0) {
        while($item = mysqli_fetch_array($fetchQuery)) {
           $out[] = $item["Name"];
        }
      }
      return $out;
   }
}
```

fil2.php

```
<?php 
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    require_once("file1.php");
    $con = dbConnect();
    $updateStat = false;
    $res = getCategory($con);
 ?>

 <div>
<label>Genre</label>
<select id="genre" name="genre" value="Please select genre">
<?php          
     foreach($res as $cat):
?>
<option value="<?php echo $cat ?>"><?php echo $cat ?></option>
<?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```